# How to compare decimal numbers available in columns of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, conditional-statements

I want to compare decimal values which are available in two columns of pandas dataframe.

I have a dataframe:

```
data = {'AA' :{0:'-14.35',1:'632.0',2:'619.5',3:'352.35',4:'347.7',5:'100'},
        'BB' :{0:'-14.3500',1:'632.0000',2:'619.5000',3:'352.3500',4:'347.7000',5:'200'}
       }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
print df1
```

**dataframe look like this :**

```
       AA        BB
0  -14.35  -14.3500
1   632.0  632.0000
2   619.5  619.5000
3  352.35  352.3500
4   347.7  347.7000
5   100    200
```

I want to compare `AA` and `BB` columns. As shown in above dataframe, values of both columns are same except **5th** row. only issue is the trailing zeros.

If both `AA` and `BB` columns are same then I want result of these comparison in third column as a `Result` i.e. `True` or `False`.

**Expected Result :**

```
       AA        BB   Result
0  -14.35  -14.35    True
1   632.0  632.0     True
2   619.5  619.5     True
3  352.35  352.35    True
4   347.7  347.7     True
5   100    200       False
```

How I can compare these decimal values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need cast column to `float` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and then compare columns, because `type` of values in columns is `string`. Then use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and as condition use boolean column `Result`:

```
print (type(df1.ix[0,'AA']))
<class 'str'>

print (type(df1.ix[0,'BB']))
<class 'str'>

df1['Result'] = df1.AA.astype(float) == df1.BB.astype(float)
df1.BB = df1.BB.mask(df1.Result,df1.AA)
print (df1)
       AA      BB Result
0  -14.35  -14.35   True
1   632.0   632.0   True
2   619.5   619.5   True
3  352.35  352.35   True
4   347.7   347.7   True
5     100     200  False
```

Another solution with [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
df1['Result'] = df1.AA.astype(float) == df1.BB.astype(float)
df1.ix[df1.Result, 'BB'] = df1.AA
print (df1)
       AA      BB Result
0  -14.35  -14.35   True
1   632.0   632.0   True
2   619.5   619.5   True
3  352.35  352.35   True
4   347.7   347.7   True
5     100     200  False
```

**Timings**:

```
#len(df) = 6k
df1 = pd.concat([df1]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [31]: %timeit df1.ix[df1.Result, 'BB'] = df1.AA
The slowest run took 4.88 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.19 ms per loop

In [33]: %timeit df1.BB = df1.BB.mask(df1.Result,df1.AA)
1000 loops, best of 3: 900 µs per loop
```

Comment: @jezrael- Please see my expected result. If both columns are equal then I want BB column same as AA.

Comment: Sorry, give me a sec.

Comment: @jezrael- which one is fast mask or ix?

Comment: What is size of `DataFrame` with real data?

Comment: @jezrael- may vary between 1500 to 10000.

Comment: It looks like `mask` solution is faster.

Comment: @jezrael- thank you for helping me most of the times.

Comment: Glad can help you! Nice day!